# (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). No converter found for return value of type: class com.test.SearchVO

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, converters

I have below source code and I am trying to run it in spring boot, but the binding is not happen and it is complaining it is not able to find a converter.

There was an unexpected error:

`(type=Internal Server Error, status=500). No converter found for return value of type: class com.test.SearchVO`.

As far as I know the spring boot does not require the jackson jars to be in path. But I have tried adding that still it is not working. I tried similar issues in different forums could not find any good answers, please help.

Is the understanding springboot will taken care of automatic conversion?

I tried posting the values I am not able to receive the value etc.

I have worked on spring application and trying spring boot for first time and as there is no spring dispatcher.

```
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringAnnotationTest {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SearchVO searchUser(@RequestBody SearchVO user) {
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getSearchUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SearchVO getSearchUser() {
        SearchVO user = new SearchVO();
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringAnnotationTest.class, args);
    }

}
```

### My pom

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is the VO Class.

```
public class SearchVO implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String empid;
private String nickname;
private String email;
private String phone; 

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "<EMPID>"+this.empid+"<NICKNAME>"+nickname+"<email>"+email+"<phone>"+phone;
}
```

}

### Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type:
 class com.test.SearchVO
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessage
ConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMeth
odProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessage
ConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMeth
odProcessor.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponse
BodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:16
5) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandle
rComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) ~
[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocabl
eHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-
webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[sprin
g-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-web
mvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapt
er.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.ja
r:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:968) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl
et.java:859) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat
-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:844) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat
-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:292) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConf
iguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConf
iguration.java:237) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilter
Internal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.ja
r:1.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(
RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInter
nal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEA
SE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Input Json
    {
        "empid": "harry",
        "nickname": "harry",
        "email": "harry@gmail.com",
        "phone": "12323232"
    }

Comment: Can you post SearchVO and complete stack trace?

Comment: I have added the stack trace and vo class.

Comment: I think you need to have getters and setters for the SearchVO class. The getters and setters are called internally to map the values. Try and see if it works.

Comment: Does `SearchVO` have a no-args constructor?

Comment: Add setter and getters for the fields

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have public getter methods for the fields of class SearchVO.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@EnableAutoConfiguration` with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

**@SpringBootApplication** consists of:

1. @Configuration - informs Spring that this is a Config class.
2. @EnableAutoConfiguration - Enable AutoConfiguration which triggers Spring Boots autoconfiguration based on clasess in classpath.
3. @ComponentScan - informs Spring to Scan for `@Components` ( i.e. `@RestController, @Controller, @Repository, @Service`)

Here is [Small Demo](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/RestControllerDemo) with your Request Mapping.

Consider moving the `@RestController` in a separate class under abc.xyz.controller package where abc.xyz is the package which contains SpringBootApplication class, this will ensure `@ComponentScan` to look for all stereotypes.

Answer (score 0):

as @Ribin suggested this kind of errors occurs when your class is missing **public** getter/setter for its properties.